# PowerShell Set-QADGroup

Tags: powershell, quest

I've gotten the following to work:

```
get-QADGroup -SearchRoot 'ex.local/' -LdapFilter '(samaccountname=test_group*)' -GroupType 'Distribution' -IncludedProperties "displayName", "mailNickname", "name", "mail" | foreach-object {
    Set-QADGroup $_ –displayName ("new_displayname")
}
```

I can't get the following properties to work :/

```
mail
mailNickname
name
cn
dn
```

The reason behind this is because we are going to be renaming every object in our AD (thousands of groups), and i need all properties to be changed.

been reading Quest everywhere however they only take up displayName as an example and nothing more advanced.

Comment: same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190501/set-qadgroup-setting-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can set some values using parameters, such as Email and DisplayName. You can set properties that do not have have a corresponding parameter using the ObjectAttributes parameter. It takes a hash table where the key name is the LDAP property name.

```
Get-QADGroup -SearchRoot 'ex.local/' -SamAccountName test_group* -GroupType Distribution -IncludedProperties displayName,mailNickname,name,mail | Foreach-Object {
    Set-QADGroup $_  -DisplayName "new_displayname" -Email "newemail" -ObjectAttributes @{attrib1="new_attrib1"; attrib2="new_attrib2"}
}
```

To rename an object use the `Rename-QADObject` cmdlet