# Set-QADGroup, setting properties

Tags: powershell, quest

I can't get the following properties to work :/

```
mail 
mailNickname 
name 
cn 
dn
```

The reason behind this is because we are going to be renaming every object in our AD (thousands of groups), and i need all properties to be changed.

been reading Quest everywhere however they only take up displayName as an example and nothing more advanced.

I've gotten the following to work though:

```
get-QADGroup -SearchRoot 'ex.local/' -LdapFilter '(samaccountname=test_group*)' -GroupType 'Distribution' -IncludedProperties "displayName", "mailNickname", "name", "mail" | foreach-object {
    Set-QADGroup $_ –displayName ("new_displayname")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

Set-QADGroup $_ -ObjectAttributes @{mail = "New_Mail"; mailNickname = "New_mailNickname"; name = "New_Name" }

`DN` and `CN` will be update when you move the group from an OU to another one.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to insert and array full of SMTP addresses?

Comment: @KarlMorrison I think you can post a new question with all the details for have an adeguate answer. Comments aren't the better way to give answers or make questions IMO ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207969/powershell-insert-smtp-array-into-proxyaddresses-for-adgroup !

Answer (score 1):

One thing though, you cannot rename the group by setting the Name property, you'll get an error. To rename the object use the `Rename-QADObject` cmdlet

Comment: Great! However that only fixes one of the X amount of properties I wish to change!

Comment: True, @Christian already gave you an answer, and I did the same for your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190468/powershell-set-qadgroup