# Powershell Insert SMTP Array into proxyAddresses for ADGroup

Tags: powershell

How would one insert an array full of smtp email addresses into an AD Group. I've tried this:

```
Set-QADGroup $_ -ObjectAttributes @{proxyAddresses = $email_smtp_array}
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Set-QADGroup $_ -ObjectAttributes @{proxyAddresses = $($email_smtp_array)}
```

This command doesn't override the Exchange policy if is set to update the adress based on the exchange configuration.